# camel delayer interceptor : works ambigously

Tags: java, apache-camel, delay

I am having a camel route which reads from `activemq` and updates inventory and i am trying to add delayer to it as follows :

```
from("activemq:{{vs.inventory.queue.name}}")
.delay(200L)
.filter( body().isNotNull() )
```

But this doesn't work as expected(delay is not for 200 ms but is everytime an ambigous delay is being set).
I referrred to http://camel.apache.org/delayer.html for this but couldn't get a working way for it.
my question is am I using this in correct way or is their something being missed.

Comment: What do you mean by ambigous?

Comment: By ambigous, I meant delay(200L) causes a delay not equivalent to 200ms but to some random no. of seconds(its more than 200ms everytime) .

Comment: The delay is using the JDK Thread.sleep so its never 100% accurate as depending on CPU thread scheduling and how buys the CPU is and whatnot. But it ought to be around 200 millis and not 5 seconds etc. Use the Camel tracer to see tracing activity where you can see from the log output what is going on